# System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I'm using an `XmlReader` retrieved using `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader`.

[Here is my input](https://gist.github.com/codyherring/5193077)

When I run this line of code:

```
XDocument currentXDoc = XDocument.Load(ktXmlReader.ReadSubtree());
```

it works the first time, reading in the first Product node as expected.

The second time it runs, I get the following exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException:
Message: Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1, position 2048.

Stacktrace:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean isQName, Int32 startOffset, Int32& colonPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlSubtreeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
```

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447208/unexpected-end-of-file-in-c-sharp-while-reading-georss-feed) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083094/web-service-call-unexpected-end-of-file-while-parsing-name-has-occurred) that were similar to mine, but I'm fairly sure my XML is well-formed (I can get it directly from running a sproc)

My ideas so far:

1. 2048 is a very suspicious number in computers.  Am I running into a 2KB limit somewhere in `XDocument` or `XmlReader`?
2. My ktXmlReader.Read() in the while loop is somehow skipping all the other nodes and going straight to the EOF

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1191911.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1191911.aspx).

My problem was that I was closing the SqlConnection with a using statement when I was getting the XmlReader.

I added the connection to my "using tower of power" and passed it as a parameter, keeping it open, and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

XmlReader execution is one way operation. You may try to reset it's position, or what is easier - [create a new reader from existing document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.createreader.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, do you have a code sample of how I could call XNode.Create from a reader, or would that require a refactor of my existing code?  It looks like to do that, I have to create an XmlReader from an XDocument, rather than an XDocument from an XmlReader

Comment: Also, I am not trying to read in multiple directions.  I'm calling ReadSubTree to read individual subtrees (Product nodes) in my input

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: I know only how to load a document from reader, not a node. But what is the difference? Except you will get multiple documents instead of nodes.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: From my XmlReader debugging experience, after reading first node it can be in incorrect state. Check that calling reader.Read() one or more times. Also in debug you can do a trick: `string t = XDocument.Load(parser).ToString()` to see what is current state and what result would you get.